# Capybara, TestUnit: testing presence of hyperlink without label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I'm using Capybara to perform some functional tests on a Ruby On Rails app.
(Everything seems properly configured, as other Capybara tests run as expected.)
In my home page I have a link to the sign up one, in this format:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/signup" class="sign_up_1">
  <div class="signUpStyle">Sign Up</div>
</a>
```

In my test:

```
page.has_link?("Sign Up", :href => '/signup')
```

always returns false. It shouldn't, should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will return false.

Since the final xpath generated would have `"//a[@href='/signup']"` which is not a valid xpath for your dom.

You can do

```
page.has_xpath?("//a[@href='#{sign_up_path}']")
```

[capybara-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/capybara-rails-2-2-0.4.1.1/Capybara/Node/Matchers.html#method-i-has_xpath-3F)

You can also verify

`page.has_link?('Sign Up', href: "http://www.example.com/signup/company")`